# Python : Issues with cmap while plotting LineStrings from a GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, normalization, geopandas, colormap

I am trying to plot a water network (alimenting buildings) with LineStrings. I would like the color of a pipe to change with the amount of water flowing through it. At the same time, I am plotting the connected buildings (shapely Polygons) with their color corresponding to their energy demand. I wrote the following lines:

```
fig,axSec = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5))

maxPowerTransm = data['PowerTransm'].max()
minPowerTransm = data['PowerTransm'].min()

norm=colors.Normalize(vmin=minPowerTransm,vmax=maxPowerTransm/10)

data.plot(ax=axSec,column='PowerTransm',cmap='viridis',norm=norm,legend=False)

cbar = fig.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='viridis',norm=norm),ax=axSec,extend='max')
cbar.set_label('Transmitted power',rotation=270,labelpad = 20)

buildings.plot(ax=axSec,column='AnnualHeat',cmap='viridis',norm=norm,legend=False)

cbar1 = fig.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='viridis',norm=norm),ax=axSec,extend='max')
cbar1.set_label('BuildingsDemand',rotation=270,labelpad=20)

axSec.axis('off')
```

And I obtain the following figure:

[image]

cmap/normalization seems to be fine while plotting polygons, but it doesn't work while plotting LineStrings as all the pipes remain blue. Am I doing it wrong or is it a known issue with GeoPandas?

Cheers

Comment: You are passing the same `norm` object (with min/max based on "PowerTransm") to both the plot for the buildings and the lines. I suppose the range of values for the lines is much smaller, hence they appear all blue.

Comment: @joris - Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately that is not the case. The lines connected to the buildings have the same value than the buildings themselves (so they should have the same color) and the values become higher as you move away from the buildings...

Comment: Then it indeed should give colors. Can you try to provide a reproducible example?